# Cordova sms plugin not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, sms

im actualy developping an app using ionic in which i must send sms to the new user containing an activation code in order to confirm his registration.

im using cordova sms plugin, and i tested it into many android version and also in windows phone 8 using phonegap developper but nothing is happening, my code is this one:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    //trying sms
    $scope.smsTry = function(loginForm){

        if(loginForm.$valid){

            //CONFIGURATION
            var options = {
                replaceLineBreaks: true, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
                android: {
                    intent: '' // send SMS without open any other app
                }
            };

            $cordovaSms.send($scope.signUpInfo.phoneNumber, 'This is some dummy text', options)
            .then(function(){
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "Ok",
                    template: "Xa a marcher"
                });
            }, function(error){
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "Error",
                    template: "putain"+error
                });

            });
        }
    }
});
```